# Accessing Multiple resources in a single authorization request

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, powerbi, microsoft-graph-api, adal

Currently, on SPA Application (**Angular 8**), we are authorizing users using "**OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant Type**" from Microsoft using ADAL services.

When the application is loaded, Adal service is initialized with a single environment configuration. So while acquiring token it uses that loaded configuration.

**Scenario**: Now we have two resources endpoint:

1. API resources
2. Power BI resources

**Workaround**: What we can do is we can first get access token for API resources using Graph API configurations then we will load Power BI configurations to get access token for Power BI resources.

**But here we have one major problem**: If again user access API resources, it has to load again the API configuration and again user will be prompted for sign-in.

**Approach 1**: We can register both Microsoft graph API resources and Power BI resources under the same AD (Active Directory), so that resources from both ends can be accessed using the same access token (I am not sure whether we can access multiple resources using same access token).

Please suggest how we can deal with this.

*Waiting for your valuable approaches in response.*

Answer (score 3):

**Question:** ***I am not sure whether we can access multiple resources using same access token?***

**Answer:**  Unfortunately, you cannot do that. All the `Microsoft Provided` authentication flow does not allow multiple `Resource/Scope` while you would request for token.

You would encounter flowing error.

> AADSTS28000: Provided value for the input parameter scope is not valid
>   because it contains more than one resource.

[image]

So you have to request with each resource/Scope for token separately.

[image]

For more details you could take a look on [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope)

Comment: While true, it is worth keeping in mind that you _can_ switch resources when refreshing a token. This isn't the same as a multi-resource token, it isn't a lot of work to orchestrate.